# Polymorphic signature of function as template argument (using lambdas)

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda, polymorphism

I'm trying hard for some hours and didn't manage to get this working.

I have a templated class spinlock:

```
template<typename T> class spinlock {
  // ...
  volatile T *shared_memory;
};
```

I'm trying to create something like this:

```
  // inside spinlock class
  template<typename F, typename... Ars>
  std::result_of(F(Args...))
  exec(F fun, Args&&... args) {
    // locks the memory and then executes fun(args...)
  };
```

But I'm trying to use a polymorphic function so that I can do this:

```
spinlock<int> spin;

int a = spin.exec([]() {
  return 10;
});

int b = spin.exec([](int x) {
  return x;
}, 10); // argument here, passed as x

// If the signature matches the given arguments to exec() plus
// the shared variable, call it
int c = spin.exec([](volatile int &shared) {
  return shared;
}); // no extra arguments, shared becomes the
    // variable inside the spinlock class, I need to make
    // a function call that matches this as well

// Same thing, matching the signature
int d = spin.exec([](volatile int &shared, int x) {
  return shared + x;
}, 10); // extra argument, passed as x... should match too

// Here, there would be an error
int d = spin.exec([](volatile int &shared, int x) {
  return shared + x;
}); // since no extra argument was given
```

Basically, I'm trying to make an `exec` function that accepts `F(Args...)` or `F(volatile T &, Args...)` as an argument.

But I can't manage to make automatic detection of types.
How could I accomplish that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, this signature will not compile:

```
// inside spinlock class
template<typename F, typename... Ars>
std::result_of(F(Args...))
exec(F fun, Args&&... args) {
  // locks the memory and then executes fun(args...)
};
```

The return type needs to be

```
typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type
```

If your compiler implements [N3436](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3436.html) then this function will not participate in overload resolution when `fun(args...)` is not a valid expression, but that is not required in C++11 and not implemented by many compilers yet.  You will need to implement your own SFINAE check to prevent `result_of` giving an error when `fun(args...)` is not valid, or rewrite it without `result_of`

```
template<typename F, typename... Args>
auto
exec(F fun, Args&&... args) -> decltype(fun(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
{
  // locks the memory and then executes fun(args...)
}
```

Then you can overload it for functions that need the additional parameter passed in:

```
template<typename F, typename... Args>
auto
exec(F fun, Args&&... args) -> decltype(fun(*this->shared_memory, std::forward<Args>(args)...))
{
  // locks the memory and then executes fun(*shared_memory, args...)
}
```

When `fun(std::forward<Args>(args)...)` is not valid the first overload will not participate in overload resolution. When `fun(*this->shared_memory, std::forward<Args>(args)...)` is not valid the second overload will not participate in overload resolution. If neither is valid the call will be ill-formed, if both are valid the call will be ambiguous.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, `typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type` was actually what I meant (I wrote kinda quickly).

But... I've tested your SFINAE (which I knew what was, but never tried using it)... worked perfectly!

Thank you very much! =D

Comment: Both your signatures worked if T isn't void; but what should I do to prevent a reference to void if T (from the class) is void? :(

Comment: I didn't understand your question until I realized you want to pass `volatile T&` but the `spinlock::shared_memory` member is a `volatile T*` so I've edited my answer to use `*this->shared_memory` ... but obviously that won't work if `T` is `void`, there's no way you can declare a function to take `volatile void&` anyway so it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Actually, I'm using `volatile ptrdiff_t *shared_memory`... instead of `*this->shared_memory`, I tried `*((volatile T *)shared_memory)`, which should make it right, but then `spinlock.h:183:57: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault: 11`... so I resolved my problem with a template specialization. Thank you for your help very much, sir! =D